# why i don't get return value javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, html

When i debug my code i can see i have value but i don't get value to createCheckBoxPlatform FN

```js
function createCheckBoxPlatform(data) {
    var platform = "";
    $.each(data, function (i, item) {
        platform += '<label><input type="checkbox" name="' + item.PlatformName + ' value="' + item.PlatformSK + '">' + item.PlatformName + '</label>' + getOS();
    });
    $('#platform').append((platform));
}

function getOS() {
    $.ajax({
        url: "/QRCNew/GetOS",
        type: "post",
        dataType: "Json",
        success: function (data) {
            var os = '<div>';
            $.each(data, function (i, item) {
                os += '<label><input type="checkbox" name="' + item.OperatingSystemName + ' value="' + item.OperatingSystemSK + '">' + item.OperatingSystemName + '</label> ';
            });
            os += '</div>';
            return os;
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: The `getOS` function is performing an asynchronous request which doesn't complete by the time your content is appended to `#platform`

Comment: you can return a value from a callback in JS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the first "A" in AJAX stands for "Asynchronous" that means, it is not executed right after it has been called. So you never get the value.

Maybe you could first, get the os list and then output what you need, like  this:

```
function createCheckBoxPlatform(myDatas) {
    $.ajax({
        url: "/QRCNew/GetOS",
        type: "post",
        dataType: "Json",
        success: function (osList) {
            var os = '<div>';
            $.each(osList, function (i, item) {
                os += '<label><input type="checkbox" name="' + item.OperatingSystemName + ' value="' + item.OperatingSystemSK + '">' + item.OperatingSystemName + '</label> ';
            });
           os += '</div>';
           $.each(myDdatas, function (i, item) {
               platform += '<label><input type="checkbox" name="' + item.PlatformName + ' value="' + item.PlatformSK + '">' + item.PlatformName + '</label>'+os
           });
           $('#platform').append((platform));

        }
    });
}
```

Comment: then, please, select as "best answer".

Answer (score 1):

I think you have to turn around your logic. The createCheckBoxPlatform loop will have completed before the getOS() ajax call returns, unless it's a synchronous call.

You could split the functions into pieces, gather the getOS data for each data point you have, then construct the checkboxes when your ajax call returns.

Answer (score 1):

You can make your ajax call async and have to make no changes to your current logic. But your execution will stop till you don't get the callback to your ajax call.

```
function getOS() {
    $.ajax({
        url: "/QRCNew/GetOS",
        type: "post",
        dataType: "Json",
        async: true,
        success: function (data) {
            var os = '<div>';
            $.each(data, function (i, item) {
                os += '<label><input type="checkbox" name="' + item.OperatingSystemName + ' value="' + item.OperatingSystemSK + '">' + item.OperatingSystemName + '</label> ';
            });
            os += '</div>';
            return os;
        }
    });
}
```